# AssertionFlowClient depreceated, trying to use ServiceAccountCredential, but it won't work

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've tried creating a DriveService using service account acting on behalf of another user.

I've copied this code from google documentation found here https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

```
    static DriveService BuildService() {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)

        {
            ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            Scope = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue(),
        };
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);
        return new DriveService(auth);
    }
```

but I get this warning when trying to build the project:

Warning 4   'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient' is obsolete: 'AssertionFlowClient is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta. Consider using ServiceAccountCredential from the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package.'

and I also get this error:

Error   11  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator' to 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer'

Then I googled ServiceAccountCredential and ended up with this code (derived from this page:  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)

```
static DriveService BuildService() {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            {
                User = "someone@mydomain.mygbiz.com", 
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });

        return service;
    }
```

When I try to build this code it seems all fine, but when I run it I get the following error.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Det går inte att hitta det begärda objektet. 
(Translated : The requested object cannot be found)

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

The error occurs on this line:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Update 2013 Oct 31
I have tried this code:

```
{
        Console.WriteLine("Drive API - Service Account");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        String serviceAccountEmail = "<some email>@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               User = "<someuser>@<mydomain>.mygbiz.com",
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "DrvMgr",
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Executing listing");
        FileList UserFiles = service.Files.List().Execute();
```

I get this error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll

Additional information: Error:"access_denied", Description:"", Uri:""

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to your p12 file is incorrect. See the [Plus.ServiceAccount](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Plus.ServiceAccount/?repo=samples) sample for a working solution.

I think that in this sample, the key.p12 was added to the project as a content file which is always copied to the output directory. Then mentioning "key.p12" file path from the code  will result in grabbing this file from the output folder.

Comment: Sorry, but no! Path is checked and all oki (I put it in C:\temp\key.p12)

And when I change the line to :
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
same error occurs:
If I alter the path to for example @"C:\tamp\key.p12" I get another error message saying :
A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Det går inte att hitta sökvägen.
(Translated : "Path Cannot be found")

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Could it be some sort of version mismatch?
Also, the Link you provided in your answer uses AssertionFlowClient, but as I mentioned in my question I get a build warning that it's not supported anymore. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, try this link - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Plus.ServiceAccount/?repo=samples. Can you follow the README file and verify that this sample works as expected? And.. just to verify - did you copy the file you downloaded from Google API Console to this location (C:\Temp\key.p12)?

Comment: Can you also attach the full stacktrace?

Comment: How to make a full stacktrace? (sorry for me being a newbie :) )
I looked through the menus in visial studio and didn't find anything on stacktraces :(
The plus.service-sample you suggested me to test worked all fine.

I've added my latest code with following error message in my original question above.

Comment: When you catch the exception, when debugging the application, you have the option to show the exception's stacktrace. You can also put a try catch on your code and catch an Exception. Then print it (ToString())

Comment: I found the answer to the last error.
In Administrators console/Security/Advanced Settings/3d party Oauth2
I should add the service account ID and scope.
Th ID is hard to come by in the new Cloud Console, but I opened the old APIs COnsole and found it.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Enjoy the library :)

Comment: @peleyal Where exactly does one find the Client ID in the new Cloud Console? After checking out the old Api Console layout I'm seeing a ton of information I couldn't find whatsoever in the new look, including the Client ID.